# Java: Properties return always null

Tags: java, properties, null, return

I have a problem. `prop.getProperty(key)` returns always null.
If I change something in the properties file and call that method (start the java program) it resets the values.
My Code:

```
    public static boolean checkProperties(){

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {

        Writer writer = new FileWriter(propertyFile);
        Reader reader = new FileReader(propertyFile);
        prop.load(reader);


        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("server-port")); // OUTPUT: null; But it is in the file!


        if(prop.getProperty("server-port") == null || prop.getProperty("server-port").equals("")){
            prop.setProperty("server-port", "2424");
            System.out.println("No port was specified in the properties file! Set port to 2424.");
        }
        if(prop.getProperty("info-text") == null || prop.getProperty("info-text").equals("")){
            prop.setProperty("info-text", "Welcome to my Game Server!");
            System.out.println("No info text was specified in the properties file! Set to 'Welcome to my Game Server!'");
        }
        prop.store(writer, "Game Server Config");
        writer.close();
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Something went wrong while checking properties file!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thanks,
Max2002_.

Comment: What is `propertyFile`? What does it point to? We can't reproduce the issue without these details.

Comment: `File propertyFile = new File("server.properties");`

Comment: "new FileWriter" always creates a new file, so you always overwrite any existing file with a new empty one

Comment: @gusto2 Thank you but how can I change it so it will work?

Comment: Can you tell us, where did you create your properties file? is the path is correct?

Comment: @sForSujit Yes, the path is correct. `propertyFile = new File("server.properties");
  if(propertyFile.exists()){
   propertiesExist = true;
  }else{
   try {
    propertyFile.createNewFile();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    printToConsole("Could not create 'server.properties' file!", LEVEL_ERROR, true);
    printToConsole(e.getMessage(), LEVEL_ERROR, true);
    return false;
   }
  }`

Answer (score 1):

It works now. Code:

```
    public static boolean checkProperties(){

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {

        //Writer writer = new FileWriter(propertyFile);
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        Reader reader = new FileReader(propertyFile);
        prop.load(reader);
        printToConsole(prop.getProperty("server-port"), LEVEL_NORMAL, true);
        if(prop.getProperty("server-port") == null || prop.getProperty("server-port").equals("")){
            prop.setProperty("server-port", "2424");
            printToConsole("No port was specified in the properties file! Set port to 2424.", LEVEL_NORMAL, true);
        }
        if(prop.getProperty("info-text") == null || prop.getProperty("info-text").equals("")){
            prop.setProperty("info-text", "Welcome to my Game Server!");
            printToConsole("No info text was specified in the properties file! Set to 'Welcome to my Game Server!'", LEVEL_NORMAL, true);
        }
        out = new FileOutputStream(propertyFile);
        prop.store(out, "Game Server Config");
        out.close();
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        printToConsole("Something went wrong while checking properties file!", LEVEL_ERROR, true);
        printToConsole(e.getMessage(), LEVEL_ERROR, true);
        return false;
    }

    try{
        port = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("server-port"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        printToConsole("Error: Can not use the port in the properties file ('" + prop.getProperty("server-port") + "')!", LEVEL_ERROR, true);
        printToConsole(e.getMessage(), LEVEL_ERROR, true);
        return false;
    }


    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static boolean checkProperties() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        boolean flag = false;
        try {
            String filename = "server.properties";
            input = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
            prop.load(input);
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("server-port"));
            if(prop.getProperty("server-port") == null){
                flag=false;
            }
            else{
                flag=true;
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Let me know if you face any issue.